# Spring Boot 2: Environment Variable Relaxed Binding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, environment-variables, netflix-eureka

I have been using environment variables to set Eureka client service url for my Spring Boot 1.5 application.

```
Environment=eureka_client_serviceUrl_defaultZone=http://myhost1:8761/eureka/,http://myhost2:8761/eureka/
```

However, this stopped working after upgrading to **Spring Boot 2**.

I have tried other combinations but none works.

```
eureka_client_service_url_defaultZone
eureka_client_service_Url_defaultZone
EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_defaultZone
EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_defaultZone
EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE
EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULT_ZONE
EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE
EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULT_ZONE
```

Does anyone know why?

Is it because [`eureka.client.serviceUrl`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientConfigBean.java#L237) is actually a `HashMap`, and the [recently tighten-up relaxed binding](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#relaxed-binding) does not work for `HashMap` with a key consisting of multiple words (i.e. `defaultZone`)?

Comment: It sounds like you are correct; it is because camel-case keys are all lowercase when bound to the map (`defaultzone`), but Spring tries to read it as `defaultZone`. Try the workaround at the bottom: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2541

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the existing issue in `spring-cloud-netflix` GitHub! Yea the workaround will work. Guess I will have to stick with the workaround until it is fixed.